# Publish .NET Website with nuget package via FTP

Tags: .net, deployment, nuget

I have a website hosted on a dedicated windows server. The application is pretty big (hundreds of pages) and has been around for over 10 years. Historically, I have always used FTP to publish the website. Effectively only moving the pages that I want moved to production.

I am a bit confused with the NUGET packages. As you install them files get copied / installed in your application. How do I safely install a NUGET package and make sure I move all the necessary files to production?

Will a NUGET install ever make changes to files such as web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your first question:**
The simplest way to handle this is to right click on your web project and click publish.  This will give you all of your publish options.  Depending on your visual studio version you may see slightly different UIs.

One of the options that is available is FTP; just enter all of the information and it will build the project and deploy it along with all of its dependencies for you.

Here is a [MSDN One-Click Publish Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx) that walks you through the process.

**To answer your second question:**
Yes, some Nuget packages make changes to the web.config.  For example, some of the logging packages (NLog, Log4Net) made changes to the web.config the last time I used them.

Comment: I don't have a very clean development environment or version control system. We also publish from different machines. It's a bit messy. So usually, when I make a change to the application, I download the files I need to work on from production, make changes and manually upload these files only.

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder So, unfortunately, since you're doing things by hand, you'll have to move the nuget packages / changes by hand as well.

I also noticed and answered your second question, that yes, some nuget packages may change your web.config

Comment: Is there an easy way to see which files a nuget package install did. i.e. which new files were brought over and which files were modified?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder If you look in your packages folder that is in the root of your code folder, you can see the packages and their respective files.  You should probably work on getting your source control / dev environment squared away and it will make all of this a lot easier